# Proof involving recursive enumerability

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

Consider the set $S = \{x : \phi^1_x(x) \ \ \text{is undefined/does not converge\} }$

This is supposed to be a set that is not recursively enumerable. How do we prove this?

My thoughts so far:

Consider the sets $T_i$ that are the domains of the functions $\phi^1_i$.

The complement, $\bar S = \{x : \phi^1_x(x) \ \ \text{is defined} \} = \{x : x \in T_x\}$ (how legit is this line)??

The complement of the complement of $S$ is then $\{x : x \not\in T_x\}$ which is not r.e. because it is not the any of the sets $T_i$

Is this OK?

Is there a better argument?

Comment: Presumably $\phi^1_x$ is the partial recursive function with index $x$? Why the superscript? You don't really need to talk about complements: it is clear that $S = \{x : x \not\in T_x\}$.

Comment: The superscript is the for clarity (arguably).
Can you give me some clue on how to proceed? It's like I'm missing some observation....

Comment: I'm not sure what the supescript clarifies, but never mind. In any case, I thought at first that you'd got the last bit wrong, but it is right: if $S = T_x$ then $x \not\in T_x$ iff $x \in S$ iff $x \in T_x$ iff $x \in T_x$, which is a contradiction.I think this is a very good argument and I don't see how to improve it (apart from skipping the bit about complements).

Answer (score 0):

As Rob Arthan says in a comment, what you've got looks like it's on the right track.

Here's something along similar lines.

Suppose that $S$ is r.e.  Since every r.e. set is the domain of a partial recursive function, it follows that there's a $k$ such that

$\phi_k(x)$ converges iff $x\in S$, for all $x$.

Hence,

$\phi_k(k)$ converges iff $k\in S$,

but the choice of $S$ implies that

$k\in S$ iff $\phi_k(k)$ doesn't converge,

a contradiction.

You may recognize the set you mention in this article...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_and_productive_sets